React and Reconciliation process
So im digging into React and how it works behind the scenes. I have found several articles but all of them seem to describe the reconciliation differently and none of them include Fiber tree and engine. I would be happy if you correct me or add something to my understanding of the process. Especially for the fiber tree
Am i right in my understanding about the fiber tree and how it works ?
Here is how I understand it:
Initial render

React begins rendering the root component. This involves calling the render method (or returning JSX in functional components) for each component in the component tree.

The fiber tree is created and populated with nodes corresponding to each component.

The virtual DOM is created based on the rendered components.

The real DOM is generated from the virtual DOM and rendered to the screen.

The fiber tree is set up to manage and optimize future updates.


State change:

New Virtual DOM Creation: A new virtual DOM is created based on the current state and props of the components.

Reconciliation: React compares the new virtual DOM with the previous virtual DOM (not the fiber tree directly) to identify what has changed.

Fiber Tree Updates: The fiber tree is the structure that keeps track of these updates. Each fiber node in the tree is updated to reflect the new state of the components and the changes detected during reconciliation. Then it passes a list of orders to the DOM, which should be applied.

Real DOM Updates: The necessary updates are then applied to the real DOM.


Checked bunch of articles but all of them have a slight difference which makes me confused.

React's internal have changed over time, it's possible the articles you read were correct in the past, but are now outdated.

1. Initial Render
Starting the Render:
When you start rendering your React application, React begins by rendering the root component (e.g., ).
Creating the Fiber Tree:
Fiber nodes are created for each component. The Fiber tree represents a data structure that keeps track of the component tree, their associated states, props, and effects. It is a linked list of JavaScript objects that represent both the virtual DOM and the React component tree.
Virtual DOM Creation:
As React traverses through each component and calls their render method (for class components) or executes their function (for function components), it creates the virtual DOM representation of the UI. However, this virtual DOM creation is intertwined with the creation of the Fiber tree.
Fiber Tree and Virtual DOM Relationship:
The Fiber tree nodes correspond to each element in the component tree and hold references to the "current" virtual DOM.
The Fiber tree is not separate from the virtual DOM; it holds information that helps React manage the virtual DOM efficiently.
Real DOM Generation:
React then generates the initial real DOM from this virtual DOM and mounts it to the actual browser DOM.
Preparing for Future Updates:
The Fiber tree is now set up to efficiently handle future updates. Each node in the Fiber tree points to its corresponding DOM node and stores the component’s state, props, etc.
2. State Change and Update Process
When a state or prop changes, React needs to re-render and update the UI.
New Virtual DOM Creation:
React re-renders the components impacted by the state or prop change. As it does this, it constructs a new Fiber tree. This new tree is built while traversing the component tree and creating new virtual DOM elements for the components that need to be updated.
Reconciliation:
Reconciliation is the process where React determines what changes have occurred. React compares the new virtual DOM with the previous one (it does this comparison using the Fiber tree structure, not the virtual DOM directly).
Fiber Tree Updates:
During reconciliation, React updates the alternate (work-in-progress) Fiber tree. There are two versions of the Fiber tree at any given time:
The current tree (representing the UI as it is currently displayed).
The work-in-progress tree (representing the UI with potential updates).
As React reconciles, it compares the work-in-progress Fiber tree with the current Fiber tree. Each Fiber node (representing a component) is evaluated to see if it should be updated, kept as is, or removed.
Calculating Changes:
React calculates the "diff" between the current and new Fiber nodes. If a node's props or state have changed, React marks it for update.
It does this efficiently using algorithms such as child reconciliation (key-based diffing for list items) and updates the alternate Fiber tree with the necessary changes.
Committing Updates:
After reconciliation, the updates are "committed" to the actual DOM. React updates the real DOM nodes with the changes determined during the reconciliation process.
This step is where React applies changes like adding, removing, or updating elements based on the Fiber tree’s instructions.
3. Key Differences and Clarifications
Fiber Tree vs. Virtual DOM:
The Fiber tree is an internal data structure in React that helps manage and schedule work (such as updates to the UI) efficiently. It represents the state and side effects of the component tree and enables React to pause, resume, and prioritize updates.
The Virtual DOM is an abstraction over the real DOM. It is essentially a lightweight copy of the real DOM used to determine what changes need to be made to the real DOM.
Reconciliation Uses the Fiber Tree:
React uses the Fiber tree to efficiently reconcile differences between the new and old states of the UI. It uses this tree to track work (like rendering components, managing state changes, etc.) and uses it during the reconciliation process to compute the changes needed to be made to the UI.
Effect List:
The Fiber nodes also form a list of effects (updates) that need to be performed in the commit phase. This is important for optimizing and scheduling work since the reconciliation phase is non-blocking and can be paused, whereas the commit phase is atomic and needs to be done all at once.
4. Modern React Features:
Concurrent Mode (React 18+):
React 18 introduces Concurrent Mode, which takes full advantage of the Fiber architecture to make rendering non-blocking, meaning React can pause work and prioritize more important updates, improving responsiveness and user experience.
Fiber Scheduling:
The Fiber tree allows React to break down work into units of work, making it possible to schedule rendering updates more flexibly. This is a key feature of React's Fiber architecture and helps with rendering large trees more efficiently by allowing React to pause and resume work.
Summary
Your understanding is on the right path, but it's important to grasp that:
The Fiber tree is integral to React's update and reconciliation process.
The Fiber tree manages and tracks component states, props, and effects to optimize rendering and updates.
Reconciliation happens using the Fiber tree to determine what parts of the UI need to be updated, not just by directly comparing the virtual DOMs.
